# '?' Should be placed at the beginning of the line in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a ReactJS project and I am getting the following error:

> `?` should be placed at the beginning of the line  `operator-linebreak`

Here is the snippet:

```
{
  index === 0 ?
    <div className='grid__row--offset--40 row'>
      <div className='small-40 columns small-centered'>
        <a className='text--white text--center text--font-size-14 button medium radius secondary' href={lang.howTiles[0].button.url}><font><font>{lang.howTiles[0].button.title}</font></font></a>
        <a href='http://localhost/slack'><img alt='Add to Slack' height='40' width='139' src='https://platform.slack-edge.com/img/add_to_slack.png' srcSet='https://platform.slack-edge.com/img/add_to_slack.png 1x, https://platform.slack-edge.com/img/add_to_slack@2x.png 2x' /></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    : null
}
```

Comment: please post entire component. Otherwise it's hard to see what's going on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is part of [ESLint's `operator-linebreak`](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/operator-linebreak) style rule:

> #### Rule Details
>
> This rule enforces a consistent linebreak style for operators.

And by default, the rule is set to allow operators to be *after* an expression *except when using `?` and `:`*:

> The default configuration is `"after", { "overrides": { "?": "before", ":": "before" } }`

Thus, put your `?` on a newline before your JSX as the rule states:

```
{
  index === 0
    ? <div>
        {/* Your JSX here */}
      <div>
    : null
}
```

If you don't like this you can reconfigure it in your `.eslintrc` or other configuration file. With what you're trying to do, try this configuration:

```
"operator-linebreak": [
  "error",
  "after",
  {
    "overrides": {
      ":": "before"
    }
  }
]
```